# I can not used javascript to control audio in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

When I click the button "play" or "pause", it does not work in Chrome:

```
<script>
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByName("player_audio");

    function play(){
        audioPlayer.play();
    }

    function pause(){
        audioPlayer.pause();
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="player_audio" controls>
<source id="audio_sources" src="http://admin.test.cnrmobile.com/18/1463652002.aac">
```

```
<p>
<button onclick="play()"> play </button>
</p>
<p>
<button onclick="pause()"> pause </button>
</p>
```

Comment: Instead of  `var audioPlayer = `document.getElementsByName`("player_audio");`  **use** `var audioPlayer = `document.getElementById`("player_audio");`

Comment: I just updated my answer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button><br> 

<audio id="myAudio" width="320" height="176">
  <source src="http://admin.test.cnrmobile.com/18/1463652002.aac" type="audio/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
</audio>

<script> 
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
    aud.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
    aud.pause(); 
} 
</script> 

</body> 
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0fjgxosu/

Your example with `document.getElementById` instead works just fine too:

```
<script>
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementById("player_audio");

    function play(){
        audioPlayer.play();
    }

    function pause(){
        audioPlayer.pause();
    }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0fjgxosu/1/

Comment: What doesn't work? It's working fine for me in Google Chrome. Have you tested the JSFiddle link? I can hear some asian man talking with music playing in the background so it is working fine.

Comment: Updated my answer with your question and changed `document.getElementById` to get it working as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I solved the problem. I do not know why need to remove <i>type="audio/ogg"</i>，otherwise it dose not work.

Comment: There is a bug in my code,need use getElementById replace getElementByName, but also encountered an unknows cause error.<script> must be placed in the <body>.Otherwise, it is not working. thank you for you  help. My development environment is  Version 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit)